# cannot inherit from web page class without runtime error

Tags: c++, qt, crash, qt5, qwebview

I have a Qt(QObject) class that, when declared, crash the application either right after initilization or few seconds after GUI show up.

The class is exactly this:

**webPage.h**

```
class webPage : public QWebPage
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    webPage(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~webPage();
};
```

**webPage.cpp**

```
webPage::webPage(QObject *parent)
    : QWebPage(parent)
{
    qDebug() << "webPage::webPage() got called!";
}

webPage::~webPage()
{
}
```

And my **mainwindow.h** class:

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e);
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();
public:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    browserControl webControl;
    webPage page; // <-- unless I remove this, the application crashs.
};
```

The constructor is like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //webControl.setPage(&page);
}
```

Can someone help me to point out the error reason? it isn't even SEGFAULT or something, start in debug mode doesn't helps, the application crashs/frooze.

Comment: @ Jack , are you using  QT += webkitwidgets ? this could be related to your issue

Comment: @MohammadKanan Yes, I'm using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly from webkitwidgets [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtwebkitwidgets-index.html):

Building the Qt WebKit module with debugging symbols is problematic on many platforms due to the size of the WebKit engine. We recommend building the module only in release mode for embedded platforms. Currently Qt WebKit will always be compiled without debugging symbols when using gcc. Take a look at **Tools/mkspecs/features/production_build.prf** if you need to change this.

As corresponded in this BUG [QTBUG-44108](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44108) ... Qt WebEngine is only available in the MSVS 2013 packages on Windows. MinGW and previous Visual Studio versions do not work at the moment, so you'll need Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition

Also, some experienced recommend doing [Porting from Qt WebKit to Qt WebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html)

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for calirfy but I've also tried  compile on relese and with `windeployqt --webkit2 --release $$(outputfile)` it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Jack, What Qt .. platform ?

Comment: :I'm using Qt with mingw (open source version)

Comment: @Jack, I also tested your code on my MinGW .. it doesn't work .. this confirms to the bug I mentioned in answer update

Comment: Thanks four answer and edit. I give up with that Qt version. I'll try update. I have already VS 2015 with C++ toolset, if I download Qt 5.10 (do I need to set up MSVS manually?) the QWebEngine will be available? I didn't find any docs mentioning that explictly.

Comment: @Jack, I have no good knowledge how to setup MSVS, but I am sure it should work cause Qt confirms ...